# Как запустить 3 терминала с разными командами одновременно ? желательно в одном окне, типа Tmux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

для работы локально нужно запускать 3 терминала с разными командами в каждом,   может есть вариант использовать Tmux для этого или что то аналогичное ?

Запуск галпа, трек лога ошибок, и команды перезапуска служб

Comment: В tmux команда `Ctrl+b "` - создает новую панель в текущем окне деля текущую панель горизонтально. `Ctrl+b %` тоже самое, только делит вертикально. `Ctrb+b курсор` - передвижение между панелями.

Comment: вопрос был как при перезагрузке компьютера, поднять такую же сессию с этими же командами в созданных терминалах в tmux. Разве он умеет создавать не только пустые терминалы ?

Comment: В вашем попросе ни слова о автозапуске после перезагрузки. Это нужно добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите в терминале `screen`

Это очень богатый менеджер терминальных сессий. В частности, в нём можно одновременно создать несколько сессий и переключаться между ними.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`$ screen -S SomeName` - создать новый сеанс. В сеансе может быть любое количество интерактивных сессий, которые будут спокойно работать в фоне и ждать вашего переключения.

Если внутри сеанса `screen` нажать `Ctrl-a d`, то сеанс уйдёт в фон, а вас вернёт обратно в тот шелл, из которого был запущен `screen`. Это капец как удобно для управления сервером по ssh. Зашел, активировал фоновый сеанс командой `$ screen -r SomeName`, поработал, нажал `Ctrl-a d`, закрыл ssh. Канал закрыт, а оно на том конце и не заметило, что пользователь отключился.

Внутри `screen` клавиши `Ctrl-a c` создают новую интерактивную сессию, а клавиши `Ctrl-a 0`, `Ctrl-a 1`, `Ctrl-a 2` ... - переключают между ними по номерам: 0 (самый первый), 1, 2 и так далее.

Более того, можно поделить экран консоли на области и на них будут параллельно выводиться интерактивные сессии.

`CTRL-a |` - разделить текущую панель по вертикали, `CTRL-a S` - по горизонтали. `CTRL-a TAB` - переключиться в следующую панель.

Возможностей много, [мануал толстый](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html). Я, если честно, пользуюсь только возможностями сворачивать сеансы на время, и переключением между сессиями внутри сеанса по `Ctrl-a 0,1,2,3...`

Сохранить и восстановить сеанс `screen` можно командой [`screen_session`](https://skoneka.github.io/screen-session/documentation.html)

Можно создать конфигурационный файл, в котором прописать запуск процессов в сессиях. Что-то вроде такого:

```
screen -t "Server" sh -c "cd ... ; server"
screen -t "Bash"
screen -t "Logs" sh -c "cd ...; tail -f log.file"
```

Запуск с кастомным конфигом: `screen -c config.file`

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от используемого терминала.

Например, для mate-terminal возможно сделать так: `mate-terminal --window -e "tail -f /var/log/Xorg.1.log" --tab -e "tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log" --tab -e "/bin/bash"`, где после "-e" в кавычках нужные вам команды или скрипты.

Привязка команды к мышовому объекту для её запуска также зависит от используемого DE или оконного менеджера.

Comment: de Gnom 40, terminal gnom ,  ubuntu 21.10

использую bash и fish